# get logged in user details with Facebook sdk and .Net

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I am following [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0) to get the logged in users details and using this code snippet below

```
 FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(string_access_token_here);
 dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/me")
 dynamic myExtraInfo = fb.Get("/me?fields=albums.limit(5).fields(name, photos.limit(2).fields(name, picture, tags.limit(2))),posts.limit(5)");
```

While I get the basic details in myInfo, in my extra info variable I only end up getting an ID
I suspect I have not crafted the URL properly. Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the `user_photos` permission for your access token before you can request albums/photos.

The query itself is fine:

[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dalbums.limit(5).fields(name%2C%20photos.limit(2).fields(name%2C%20picture%2C%20tags.limit(2)))%2Cposts.limit(5)&version=v2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dalbums.limit%285%29.fields%28name%2C%20photos.limit%282%29.fields%28name%2C%20picture%2C%20tags.limit%282%29%29%29%2Cposts.limit%285%29&version=v2.0)

Comment: I tried that link with all the permissions selected in the get access tokens pop up. All I get is {"error": "Invalid response"}

Comment: Remove the slash infront of /me and try again please

Comment: thanks that worked in the graph API explorer.. cant seem to get posts properly in my code.. in the graph explorer it shows properly all the last 5 posts, but in my code it just shows the last post and seems to only show id and created date of the remaining posts. when I change the limit to 50 I see more messages till I reach the paging limit.. what could be the reason for this?

Comment: using /me/feed seems to show all the posts.. whats the difference between the two ?